# Parallel csv processing with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a function that reads a csv file and returns manipulated (by LINQ) results. I need to open each file twice, as I need to slice the data very differently for different uses and with the "A Fast CSV Reader" on codeproject that I m using it is faster to read it twice and do manipulation with LINQ directly each time than reading it into DataTable.

Individually each function call (imppow or impfuel) takes just over 2 secs.

Simple for loop for six calls (takes 13secs):

```
string[] pathstring = { @"C:\Temp\Hourly1.txt", @"C:\Temp\Hourly2.txt", @"C:\Temp\Hourly3.txt" };
string[] pathgran = { "M", "Q", "Y" };
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
     var respow = imppow(pathstring[i], pathgran[i]);
     Console.WriteLine(respow[0]);

     var resfuel = impfuel(pathstring[i], pathgran[i]);
     Console.WriteLine(resfuel[0]);
}
```

Parallelizing like this shaves off 3 secs but not more:

```
Parallel.For(0, 3, (i) =>
{
    var respow = imppow(pathstring[i], pathgran[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(respow[0]);

    var resfuel = impfuel(pathstring[i], pathgran[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(resfuel[0]);
});
```

As said one call takes roughly 2 secs. Can I get the runtim down further by using multithreading or sth?
Thanks.

Below one of the functions:

```
static object[] impfuel(string filepath, string gran)
{  
    using (CsvReader csv =
           new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filepath), true))
    {
        csv.SupportsMultiline = false;
        var results = csv.Select(r => new { yr = r[1], qr = r[3], mt = r[4], tar = r[7], mac = r[8], fuel = r[9], rg = r[10], rt = r[11], fp = r[22], fi = r[24] })
                         .Where(a => a.rt == "F")
                         .GroupBy(a => new { a.rg, a.fuel, a.tar, a.mt })
                         .Select(g => new { Rpg = g.Select(a => a.rg).First(), Fue = g.Select(a => a.fuel).First(), Tari = g.Select(a => a.tar).First(), Mon = g.Select(a => a.mt).First(), AverageA = g.Average(a => double.Parse(a.fp)), SumA = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.fi)) })
                         .ToArray();
        return results;
    }
}

static object[] imppow(string filepath, string gran)
{  
using (CsvReader csv =
       new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filepath), true))
{
    csv.SupportsMultiline = false;
    var results = csv.Select(r => new { yr = r[1], qr = r[3], mt = r[4], tar = r[7], mac = r[8], rg = r[10], rt = r[11], pp = r[17], pi = r[19] })
                     .Where(a => a.rt == "M")
                     .GroupBy(a => new { a.rg, a.tar, a.mt })
                     .Select(g => new { Rpg = g.Select(a => a.rg).First(), Tari = g.Select(a => a.tar).First(), Mon = g.Select(a => a.mt).First(), AverageA = g.Average(a => double.Parse(a.pp)), SumA = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.pi)) })
                     .ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you cache the files in memory & use MemoryStreams?  Eliminating File I/O might help.

Comment: Parallel.For() is using multiple threads (if necessary and available)

Comment: thanks Dan! do you have a link or sample? never used memorystreams

Comment: yes Martin but if it was completely parallel shouldnt the run time go down more?

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: @npvh However you're opening the file within your `imppow` and `impfuel` methods (either a `StreamReader` or `File.Open` or something), call that once within your main method, cache the `Stream` or `bytes` or whatever is returned, then pass that into `imppow` and `impfuel`.

Comment: Take a look at the [doc for MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).  It's just another Stream and relatively easy to use.

Comment: I m using a Stream (see above for code)... I have 2 CPUs. I will try to give the memory stream a go. thanks all!

Comment: @npvh "if it was completely parallel shouldnt the run time go down more?"* It can only run in as many threads as you have cores (at least simultaneously, which is what actually speeds things up). With 2 cores, the fastest you can hope for is (time/2), so half the time (not counting the overhead of having to share cores with other things).

Comment: It looks like you're doing very little work on the CPU -- you're probably I/O bound. Reading the file in twice probably isn't helping either.

Comment: Can you post the code for `imppow`?

Comment: You may want to take a look at my articles on reading CSV as a stream and using LINQ over them at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject. Ultimately to solve your perf issue, you need to do some profiling to find where your bottleneck really is. As others mentioned, using Parallel.For only solves the issue if you are CPU bound. It doesn't address memory allocation and garbage collection, excessive iterations, etc.

Comment: @CoryNelson: imppow is virtually identical apart from the LINQ statement. The issue is, i cannot combine them because there is a field (in my where statement) that signifies a record type and if I dont filter for it, I get lots of blanks which I then cannot parse to double...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never tell the size of the files, is it a few kilobytes or at we talking megabytes?
Reading the file once would limit the slow IO.

I would read the file once and while reading it I would put the content into two different lists.

```
string[] pathstring = { @"C:\Temp\Hourly1.txt", @"C:\Temp\Hourly2.txt", @"C:\Temp\Hourly3.txt" };
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
     List<Content> powList = new List<Content>();
     List<Content> fuelList = new List<Content>();
     ReadFile(pathstring[i], ref powList, ref fuelList);
     var respow = imppow(powList);
     Console.WriteLine(respow[0]);

     var resfuel = impfuel(fuelList);
     Console.WriteLine(resfuel[0]);
}

void ReadFile(string filepath, ref List<Content> powList, ref List<Content> fuelList)
{
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filepath), true))
    {
        csv.SupportsMultiline = false;
        foreach(Content content in csv.Select(r => new Content(){ yr = r[1], qr = r[3], mt = r[4], tar = r[7], mac = r[8], fuel = r[9], rg = r[10], rt = r[11], pp = r[17], pi = r[19], fp = r[22], fi = r[24] }))
        {
           if (content.rt == "F")
               fuelList.Add(content);
           else if (content.rt = "M")
               powList.Add(content);
        }
    }
}

static object[] impfuel(List<Content> fuelList)
{  
    var results = fuelList.GroupBy(a => new { a.rg, a.fuel, a.tar, a.mt })
                     .Select(g => new { Rpg = g.Select(a => a.rg).First(), Fue = g.Select(a => a.fuel).First(), Tari = g.Select(a => a.tar).First(), Mon = g.Select(a => a.mt).First(), AverageA = g.Average(a => double.Parse(a.fp)), SumA = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.fi)) })
                     .ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

}

You can make imppow and the Content class your self.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I m sorry I should have mentioned that: 1 file is 60megs, we are talking 500,000 rows and 26 columns. I will try your answer and see how quick it is

Comment: If you want to make it multithreaded, you could ReadFile and run impfuel and imppow in parallel, e.g. async and await (search SO for an example of how to do that.)

Comment: @casperah: Thanks! this works and brings it down by another second, so I started with 12-13secs, my parallel with reading file 6 times was 8, your method with storing it into two lists gets it down to 7. I will try to include async and await now and sees whether that shaves off another second...